# How to disable yarn interactive prompt for yarn upgrade

Tags: node.js, bash, yarnpkg

I am adding the yarn upgrade command to a bash file.
I want to run command to upgrade a specific package to a specific version.

```
yarn upgrade mypackage@5.9.5
```

But if the specific version is not found in remote npm repository currently yarn opens up a prompt to select from available versions, like this one:

```
Couldn't find any versions for "mypackage" that matches "5.9.5"
Please choose a version of "mypackage" from this list: (Use arrow keys)
```

This is not working well in the bash file. What I need is a simple error that package was not found and an exit with non 0 exit code.

Is it possible to do that?
Is there an option in yarn to disable this interactive selector or maybe there is a bash trick to disable this interaction and turn in into a simple exit code?

Comment: You could experiment with I/O redirection with `yarn upgrade mypackage@5.9.5 </dev/null`. You could also try to see if the `--non-interactive` flag happens to work with `upgrade` though it is not documented as such.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yarn upgrade` with the `--non-interactive` flag. You will get a non-zero exit code if it fails

```
$ yarn upgrade webpack-merge@4.2.29 --non-interactive
yarn upgrade v1.13.0
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find any versions for "webpack-merge" that matches "4.2.29"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade for documentation about this command.
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on unix, you can use the command `yes` to pipe an empty string to everything and it will act as if it made the first selection to the list, i.e.

By default, yes, emits a stream of `y` characters, but if you give it an argument it will emit that stream over and again to stdout. so in this case, you'll use:

`yes " " | yarn upgrade webpack-merge@4.2.29`

`--non-interactive` will fail, and you may (or probably) don't want that.